# android os networkonmainthreadexception error in android

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error "android.os.networkonmainthreadexception" while trying to pull a json data from an url.
Would some tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the StrictMode.ThreadPolicy. It was introduced since API Level 9 and the default thread policy had been changed since API Level 11, which in short, does not allow network operation (eg: HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection) get executed on UI thread. if you do this, you get NetworkOnMainThreadException.

The recommended way of solving this is by Using an **AsyncTask** so that the network request does not block the UI thread.

You can override this thread policy by adding the below code into your main activity’s onCreate() method.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: Please do not recommend that developers override the policy.

Comment: Adding the code did work for me. Let me try to use AsyncTask.